# Multiple pickerviews with multiple textfield inputviews Swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uipickerview

I've been searching through the forum and nothing has helped.
I am using 4 text fields in one view controller, and for each textfield, I am using a separate pickerView as the inputViews for the textFields (4pickers).

When I click on the first textField, pickerView1 successfully appears and the textfield displays the data, however when I click on the second, third and fourth textfields,the first pickerView appears.
I suspect the error lies in the inputView declarations.

And I would so appreciate it if you could help add a "done" button to the pickerView.

My code:

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate
{

    @IBOutlet var pickerView1: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet var pickerView2: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet var pickerView3: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet var pickerView4: UIPickerView!

    @IBOutlet var textField1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var textField2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var textField3: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var textField4: UITextField!

    var hazards = ["a","b", "c"]
    var reasons = ["d", "e", "f"]
    var site = ["v","h","i","j"]
    var line = ["k", "l","m", "n"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        pickerView1 = UIPickerView()
        pickerView2 = UIPickerView()
        pickerView3 = UIPickerView()
        pickerView4 = UIPickerView()
        pickerView1.delegate = self
        pickerView2.delegate = self
        pickerView3.delegate = self
        pickerView4.delegate = self

        self.textField1.inputView = self.pickerView1;
        self.textField2.inputView = self.pickerView2;
        self.textField3.inputView = self.pickerView3;
        self.textField4.inputView = self.pickerView4;
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int  {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        if pickerView.tag == 0 {
            return hazards.count
        } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            return reasons.count
        } else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
            return  site.count
        } else if  pickerView.tag == 3 {
            return line.count
        }
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {

        if pickerView.tag == 0 {
            return hazards[row]
        } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            return reasons[row]
        } else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
            return site[row]
        } else if pickerView.tag == 3 {
            return line[row]
        }

        return ""
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)  {

        if pickerView.tag == 0 {
            textField1.text = hazards[row]
        } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            textField2.text = reasons[row]
        } else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
            textField3.text = site[row]
        } else if pickerView.tag == 3 {
            textField4.text = line[row]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's a place to get started with adding a Done button: http://blog.swierczynski.net/2010/12/how-to-create-uipickerview-with-toolbar-above-it-in-ios/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're using the picker views' `tag` property to decide which array is the data source for a given picker view, but you didn't set the tags initially. The `tag` defaults to zero, so all four picker views are showing the same data. After instantiating your picker views, add this:

```
pickerView1.tag = 0
pickerView2.tag = 1
pickerView3.tag = 2
pickerView4.tag = 3
```

Comment: I've already set the tags for the pickerviews using xcode, i'm sure they display different data as if i remove the inputview calls, and display the pickers on the page, they display different data. Also that tutorial is in objective C, which i dont understand.

Comment: Do you mean you set the tags in your storyboard? When you create new picker views (i.e., with this code: `pickerView1 = UIPickerView()`) none of that setup applies.

Comment: Thank you!!! It worked! I had the tags set in the attribute inspector but not the code.

Comment: Could you help talk me through how to convert the code in that tutorial for the done button in to swift??