# Multiple UIPickerViews - UIPickerView not visible

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uipickerview

I'm writing an car rental app where the user has to specify the pickup and return location of the car.

In the first step, the user has to select the zone/region of the pickup/return office. After he has selected a region, a he has to choose from a list of offices available in this region.

For the selection of the office I use 4 UIPicker views.
I've managed to handle the region UIPickers. They show up properly. Depending on what region the user has chosen, I would like to show a second UIPicker and populate it with the respective data.

I have problems with the second UIPickers (office pickers). I don't know how I can make them visible (see also the screenshots of my simulator).Somehow they don't show up. Below is the code snippet of my controller.

```
class NewReservationViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var pickupLocationTextView: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var returnLocationTextView: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var pickupZoneUIPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet var pickupOfficeUIPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet var returnZoneUIPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet var returnOfficeUIPicker: UIPickerView!


var zones: [String] = ["Zone1", "Zone2", "Zone3"]
var offices : [String : [String]] = [
    "Zone1" : ["Hotel1", "Hotel2", "Hotel3"],
    "Zone2" : ["Hotel4", "Hotel5"],
    "Zone3" : ["Hotel6", "Hotel7", "Hotel8", "Hotel9"]
]

var pickupZoneUIPickerValue = ""
var pickupOfficeUIPickerValue = ""

var returnZoneUIPickerValue = ""
var returnOfficeUIPickerValue = ""


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Hide all available pickers first
    pickupZoneUIPicker.hidden = true
    pickupOfficeUIPicker.hidden = true
    returnZoneUIPicker.hidden = true
    returnOfficeUIPicker.hidden = true

    //Now init the 2 zone pickers that will be shown first
    pickupZoneUIPicker = UIPickerView()
    returnZoneUIPicker = UIPickerView()

    //Set data source to this controller
    pickupZoneUIPicker.dataSource = self
    returnZoneUIPicker.dataSource = self

    //Set delegates to this class
    pickupZoneUIPicker.delegate = self
    returnZoneUIPicker.delegate = self

    //set the text fields as input views
    pickupLocationTextView.inputView = pickupZoneUIPicker
    returnLocationTextView.inputView = returnZoneUIPicker

    //get Toolbars for both pickers
    pickupLocationTextView.inputAccessoryView = getPickerToolbar("pickupZoneDone")
    returnLocationTextView.inputAccessoryView = getPickerToolbar("returnZoneDone")

    //set default values for zone pickers in case the user clicks Done immediately
    pickupZoneUIPickerValue = zones[0]
    returnZoneUIPickerValue = zones[0]
}

/*
 UIToolbar Callbacks for UIPickers
*/
//called when user has selected the pickup zone in the first text field
func pickupZoneDone(){

    //hide the picker
    pickupZoneUIPicker.hidden = true

    //Now setup a new UIPickerView
    pickupOfficeUIPicker = UIPickerView()
    pickupOfficeUIPicker.dataSource = self
    pickupOfficeUIPicker.delegate = self

    //set default value
    pickupOfficeUIPickerValue = offices[pickupZoneUIPickerValue]![0]

    pickupOfficeUIPicker.hidden = false
    pickupOfficeUIPicker.becomeFirstResponder()
    pickupOfficeUIPicker.reloadInputViews()
    pickupOfficeUIPicker.reloadAllComponents()


}
//called when user has selected the return zone in the second text field
func returnZoneDone(){

}



//Setup the pickerViewToolbar variable of this class
func getPickerToolbar(doneCallbackMethodName: String) -> UIToolbar{


    let pickerViewToolbar = UIToolbar()
    pickerViewToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    pickerViewToolbar.translucent = true
    pickerViewToolbar.sizeToFit()



    let doneWithZoneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: Selector(doneCallbackMethodName))
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)


    pickerViewToolbar.setItems([spaceButton, doneWithZoneButton], animated: false)
    pickerViewToolbar.userInteractionEnabled = true

    return pickerViewToolbar

}

// MARK: UIPickerView and UIPickerViewDataSource delegate Methods
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    //all pickers only have one component (wheels)
    return 1
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    if pickerView == pickupZoneUIPicker || pickerView == returnZoneUIPicker {
        return zones.count
    }
    else if pickerView == pickupOfficeUIPicker {
        return offices[pickupOfficeUIPickerValue]!.count
    }
    else //pickerView == returnOfficeUIPicker
    {
        return offices[returnOfficeUIPickerValue]!.count
    }
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView == pickupZoneUIPicker || pickerView == returnZoneUIPicker{
        return zones[row]
    }
    else if pickerView == pickupOfficeUIPicker {
        return offices[pickupOfficeUIPickerValue]![row]
    }
    else { //if pickerView == returnOfficeUIPicker
        return offices[returnOfficeUIPickerValue]![row]
    }


}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if pickerView == pickupZoneUIPicker {
        pickupZoneUIPickerValue = zones[row]
    }
    else if pickerView == returnZoneUIPicker {
        returnZoneUIPickerValue = zones[row]
    }
    else if pickerView == pickupOfficeUIPicker {
        pickupOfficeUIPickerValue = offices[pickupZoneUIPickerValue]![row]
    }
    else { //if pickerView == returnOfficeUIPicker
        returnOfficeUIPickerValue = offices[returnOfficeUIPickerValue]![row]
    }

}
```

[image: Zone/region selection]
[image: Dynamic hotel UIPickerView not showing up]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried calling `reloadInputViews()` on `pickupLocationTextView` in `pickupZoneDone`?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately nothing happens.

Comment: Have you tried using the .tag property? See for more info <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26488250/mutiple-pickerviews-with-multiple-textfield-inputviews-swift>

Answer (score 0):

Check that delegate is set in all textfields in main storyboard